# Distance from button contents to button frame

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, button, styles

I have several buttons in my app and would like to change the red marked distance in my screenshot to "0". So that the number inside the button is as big as possible.

[image]

I just don't know how this is possible.

Here my .xml code:

```
<Button

android:id="@+id/b20"

android:layout_width="wrap_content"

android:layout_height="wrap_content"

android:insetLeft="6dp"

android:insetRight="6dp"

android:text="@string/_20"

android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Large"

app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/b16"

app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/b19"

app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"

app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"

app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

I appreciate every hint or advice.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
            android:paddingVertical="20dp"
```

it may help you if you want to increase the size of button or

```
    android:textSize="15sp"
```

it will increase the font size and the button will become bigger automatically

Comment: Thanks, I already tried this. Let's say I have Not enough space to make the button bigger. Is there really no solution for this?

Comment: @pythonnewbie it is not enough code to help you